# Email work with one or a few " To" but not large amounts. Is there anything wrong with this code?

Tags: c#, email

The below code works when there are a few element in the "To" list but if i add a large amount, noone recieves the mail  .  Any clues why this code below would work with a few elments but not with more than one.  Also, is there anyway to debug this in terms of actually seeing what is getting sent out from the mail server?

```
    public static void SendMail(string fromEmailAddress_, string[] toEmailAddress_, string[] ccAddress_, string[] bccAddress_, string subject_, string body_, Attachment[] attachments_)
    {
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.From = new MailAddress(fromEmailAddress_);
        foreach (string email in toEmailAddress_)
        {
            if (IsValidEmail(email))
            {
                msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(email.Trim()));
            }
        }
        if (ccAddress_ != null)
        {
            foreach (string email in ccAddress_)
            {
                if (IsValidEmail(email))
                {
                    msg.CC.Add(new MailAddress(email.Trim()));
                }
            }
        }

        if (bccAddress_ != null)
        {
            foreach (string email in bccAddress_)
            {
                if (IsValidEmail(email))
                {
                    msg.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(email.Trim()));
                }
            }
        }

        if (attachments_ != null)
        {
            foreach(Attachment attachment in attachments_)
            {
                msg.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            }
        }

        msg.Subject = subject_;
        msg.Body = body_;
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        msg.Priority = MailPriority.High;

        NetworkCredential basicAuthenticationInfo = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("admin@salemgolfclub.org", "password");
            SmtpClient c = new SmtpClient("mail.salemgolfclub.org");
            c.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            c.Credentials = basicAuthenticationInfo;
        try
        {
            c.Send(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is most likely due to some security restriction on the mail server, and has nothing to do with how it is implemented in your .Net app. I would check the log files on the server.

If you want to test your mailing code independently from a specific mail server, you could configure your app to store the mails as files on your local hard drive instead. The following config snippet does the trick:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
        <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="c:\some\dir\here"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

You need to use the default constructor of SmtpClient for this to work, instead of specifying the server name in the code.

Comment: found out i had a 50 recipient limit on the mail server